# What does code generation mean in avro - hadoop

Tags: hadoop, avro

Kindly regret if this question is silly. I am finding it difficult to get what it really means.When i read 'Hadoop the definitive guide' it says that the best advantage of avro is that code generation is optional in Avro. [This link](http://rishavrohitblog.blogspot.in/search/label/avro) has a program for avro serialization/deserialization with/without code generation. Could some one help me in understanding exactly what with/without code generation mean and the real context of the same.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It's not a silly question -- it's actually a very important aspect of Avro.

**With** code-generation usually means that *before* compiling your Java application, you have an Avro schema available.  You, as a developer, will use an Avro compiler to generate a class for each record in the schema and you use these classes in your application.

In the referenced link, the author does this: `java -jar avro-tools-1.7.5.jar compile schema student.avsc`, and then uses the `student_marks` class directly.

In this case, each instance of the class `student_marks` inherits from `SpecificRecord`, with custom methods for accessing the data inside (such as `getStudentId()` to fetch the `student_id` field).

**Without** code-generation usually means that your application doesn't have any specific necessary schema (for example, it can treat different kinds of data).

In this case, there's no `student` class generated, but you can still read Avro records in an Avro container.  You won't have instances of `student`, but instances of `GenericRecord`.  There won't be any helpful methods like `getStudentId()`, but you can use methods `get("student_marks")` or `get(0)`.

Often, using specific records with code generation is easier to read, easier to serialize and deserialize, but generic records offer more flexibility when the exact schema of the records you want to process isn't known at compile time.

A helpful way to think of it is the difference between storing some data in a helpful handwritten POJO structure versus an `Object[]`.  The former is much easier to develop with, but the latter is necessary if the types and quantity of data are dynamic or unknown.